# R API Api Key HTTR

Tags: r, api-key, httr

It's my first accessing an API with HTTR library, it seems pretty straightforward. The problem I have is that I don't know where to put my API Key for authentication.

It is still giving me the error 403, which is the one that says I'm not authorized to access.

I do have my API Key. I have tried these two ways, but non is working.

Any ideas?

```
url <- "https://cbsaust.api-us1.com/api/3/"
api_key <- ""
API_URL <- paste0(url,api_key)

res <- httr::GET(API_URL)
test <- httr::GET("https://cbsaust.api-us1.com/api/3/", 
            httr::add_headers(Authorization = api_key))
```

Comment: think you are trying to use the API keys in the URL. have you tried passing it in the header instead?

Comment: There's not just one way to pass API credentials. Every website out there may have a different expectation of how they want the value passed. Is there documentation for the API endpoint you are trying to use where they describe exactly what they expect? It seems very odd that you are including the key in both the URL and the Authorization header. And when including an Authorization header with a token, it's often more common to see a "Bearer" in front of the key. But again, there's no standard way that works for all websites.

Answer (score 0):

This was the simple solution.

```
headers = c('Api-Token' = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

res <- VERB("GET", url = "https://websitet.api-us1.com/api/", add_headers(headers))
```